# Filling seed data that needs another table for one of its values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, random-seed

I'm trying to create seed data for products but A product has a price field filled in by the price model from a selection of prices.

When I fill in the seed file as follows I get an error saying that 'Price expected, got a String'. I understand why this is happening but I don't know how to fill in the price field in my seed data.

I've looked at other questions similar to this but keep getting errors

Here is what my product seed looks like at the moment with the 'got a String' error

```
if !Product.exists?(:product_title => 'test7')
Product.create(
    product_title: 'test7',
    product_desc: 'Available in a range of colours and designs.',
    price: '9.99',
    department: 'Accessories',
    display_on_home_page: true,
    is_highlight_product: false,
    start_date: '13/07/2013')
end
```

price has an 'attached_file' and a 'value' that is in-putted as a string.

I know I've gotten close but can't get the syntax right, any help is very much appreciated.

Edit 1

Price model

```
class Price < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :products

attr_accessible :value, :image_attachment, :price_id

attr_accessor :image_file_name
attr_accessor :image_content_type
attr_accessor :image_file_size
attr_accessor :image_updated_at

has_attached_file :image_attachment, 
:styles => {
    :normal_page_size => "81x85>",
    :large_page_size => "140x140#"
    },:default_url => "/assets/missing_images/:style/missing.png"
def image_url
    if self.image.nil?      
        "/assets/thumb_sq/missing.png"
    else
        self.image_attachment.url(:normal_page_size)
    end
end
end
```

Comment: You should show us EXACTLY what price is.

Comment: Typically adding products to a database isn't a "seed" operation.

Comment: I need to add a small number of products to the database so as to display them on the home page. This is necessary for formatting the front page of the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `price: '9.99'` do `price: Price.create(value: '9.99')`

Comment: worked perfectly, and its so obvious, thanks for taking the time.
I was overcomplicating it with my attempts.